# Java EntityManager merge and @PrePersist

Tags: java, entity, entitymanager

I use this piece of line to merge:

```
partner = em.merge(partner);
```

and this is in my entity:

```
@PrePersist
public void updateModificationDate(){
    this.lastModificationDate = new Date();
}
```

So as you can see, I want to keep up when the entity was last changed,

but the method never gets called,

Anybody an idea of what I could do?

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your entity the following annotation:

```
@EntityListeners(SaveOrUpdateDateListener.class)
```

And actually listener would be:

```
public class SaveOrUpdateDateListener {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setDate(final CertApplication entity) {
        final Date now = new Date();
        entity.setUpdated(now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events) and discover why prepersist is not called. Also I think that you can use `@Version` annotation to keep entity last modification date.

Comment: But I want to use a Date as lostmodificationdate. How can i fix this?

Comment: You can use Date this way:
`@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "UPD_ON", nullable = false)
private Date updatedOn;`

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing em.flush() but I'm not very sure whether forcing a flush is a good practice.